# CSS pseudo-classes and jQuery animation?

Tags: jquery, css

I'd like to use CSS's :hover pseudo-class to control a drop-down on hover. That's been accomplished. The tricky part, however, is animating that drop-down. I do *not* want to rely on jQuery to make the menu show up at all, it should work perfectly (albeit without the fade animation) with JS off. Is there a way to 'hook' into CSS's :hover and instead run some jQuery (fade the menu in, and out on hover out), if JS is turned on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

very roughly, say you have `<ul class="css-hovers">`

then in jquery `$('ul').removeClass('css-hovers').addClass('js-hovers');`
- so the css and js hovers wont run at the same time ..

and add your jquery hovers:
`$('ul.js-hovers').hover(function () { ... etc - see Darko Z's answer`

Comment: @zach - This is exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: Nice! Shoulda thought of that, but that's a very effective, lean solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thats fairly easy to accomplish with jQuery. Just have a look at this documentation: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Just remember to suppress the CSS hover when JS/jQuery is available

Comment: That's the question, though, I'm perfectly aware of .hover(), I need to figure out exactly how to suppress the CSS hover.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Superfish jQuery plugin](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/), it just adds some fancy animation and hoverIntent support to a standard suckerfish CSS menu system. You can either just drop it in and move on to other things or study the source to find out how it works.